# Is it possible to wait for a callback in the same thread?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Here is the thing. While in UI thread, I posted an async callback in the UI thread. Is it possible to wait for the callback and execute synchronously

A good example would be to wait for WebView's evaluateJavascript while in UI thread.

```
//In the UI thread
webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:.....", callback)
//Needs to be sure that the callback is completed
dosomething()
```

I know it's recommended to put `dosomething()` inside the `callback`. But in certain circumstance, it is not safe, like performing actions in `onPause()`. If you don't wait synchronously, then the view can be destroyed at any time.

```
override fun onPause(){
    webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:.....", callback)
    doNotContinueUntilCallbackCompletes()
    super.onPause()
}
```

Since we are in the same thread as the callback, so `CountDownLatch` didn't work. It blocks the entire UI thread. And since we need to access `webView`, so we have to make the `callback` in the UI thread.

So what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not in the general case, no.  For one thing, a callback is not necessarily asynchronous.  A callback could occur on the same thread.  In which case waiting for it would be instant deadlock of that thread. An example of a callback that is rarely asynchronous is a visitor pattern that walks an object hierarchy.  Another would be a library that posts back to the main thread when done, like Volley.

Now if you assume the callback will be called asynchronusly, then you could use a Future to wait for it-  or just signal a semaphore in your callback (which is more or less what a future would do).

However, you almost never want to do this, and NEVER from the UI thread. If you did it from the UI thread the entire app would freeze.  That's why you do things on other threads.  Waiting for it in that case would always be a mistake.  If it wasn't from the UI thread there are some use cases for it (mainly when interacting with libraries that do their own threading), but if you're going to do work on another thread and get a callback-  why not just do the work now on this thread?

Also, doing it in onPause like that would probably trip a watchdog timer and cause the entire app to crash uncleanly.  Lifecycle functions have a limited time to run.

Comment: Yes, it is undesirable to wait in UI thread and especially 'onPause' method. But sometimes it is needed to retrieve some pretty costly data from webview before exit.  Keeping a copy of that data CAN solve the problem, however if the thread can wait for webView.evaluateJavascript then it would be much better.

Comment: @First_Strike The application doesn't magically exit at the end of onPause, nor is it instantly garbage collected (or even instantly eligible for it).  Its acceptable to start an async task in onPause and have it run in the background while other things happen on the phone.  The View actually CANT be destroyed at any time, it has to follow the rules of Java garbage collection.  As long as any GC root object (like a thread) has a reference to it, it can't be cleaned up.